# Change the background of a UILabel in ViewController when I slide left or right a Slider in a Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swiftyuserdefaults

I need to change 1 label background using a Sliders located in a Settings Bundler.
When I slide to right my UILabel background need to get a **shade** of red and when I change to left my UILabel need to get a **shade** of black.

Here I have 3 screenshots with my Bundle, ViewController and my code.

[image: Bundle]

[image: View Controller]

```
 // slider 1 - When I slide to left: Shade of black    Slide to right: shade of red
    if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderOne_preference") >= 0 &&  userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderOne_preference") <= 49 {
        labelOne.backgroundColor = .black
    }
    else if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderOne_preference") > 49 &&  userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderOne_preference") <= 100 {
        labelOne.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    // slider 2 - When I slide to left: Shade of black    Slide to right: shade of blue
    if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderTwo_preference") >= 0 &&  userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderTwo_preference") <= 49 {
        labelTwo.backgroundColor = .black
    }
    else if userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderTwo_preference") > 49 &&  userDefaults.integer(forKey: "sliderTwo_preference") <= 100 {
        labelTwo.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Always post text as actual text.

Comment: Where in your project is this code (viewDidLoad etc)? Also, what is the problem you are having?

Comment: My viewDidLoad is on the top. But I need help with this 2 conditions for that 2 sliders from my bundled.